# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') at ProductDetails (ProductDetails.js:17:1)

Tags: reactjs

Below is the image of my console :
[cannot read properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqy07.png)

**The following is my productDetails page code:**

```
import React,{useEffect}from 'react'
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel"

import "./ProductDetails.css"
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction'



const ProductDetails = ({match}) => {
    const dispatch=useDispatch();


    const{product,loading,error}=useSelector((state)=>state.productDetails)
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id))
    }, [dispatch,match.params.id])
    
  return (
    <>
    <div className="ProductDetails">
        <div>
           <Carousel>
                { product.images &&
                  product?.images?.map((item, i) => (
                    <img
                      className="CarouselImage"
                      key={item.url}
                      src={item.url}
                      alt={`${i} Slide`}
                    />
                  ))}
              </Carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

**
The following is my App.js Code**

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './component/layout/Header/Header';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom"
import WebFont from "webfontloader"
import React from "react"
import Footer from './component/layout/Footer/Footer'
import Home from './component/Home/Home';
import Loader from './component/layout/Loader/Loader';
import ProductDetails from './component/Product/ProductDetails';
function App() {
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    WebFont.load({
      google:{
        families:["Roboto","Droid Sans","Chilanka"]
      }
    })
  },[])
  return (
      <Router>

        <Header/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
      </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

The following is my the getProductDetails function which is used in productDetails page:

```
   export const getProductDetails=(id)=>async(dispatch)=>{
        try{
                dispatch({type:PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST})

                const {data}=await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);

                dispatch({
                    type:PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
                    payload:data.product,
                })
        }
        catch(error){
            dispatch({
                type:PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
                payload:error.response.data.message,
            })
        }
    }
    
    export const clearErrors=()=>async(dispatch)=>{
        dispatch({type:CLEAR_ERRORS})
    }
```

I was expecting that when i click the product its productdetails page should open but it does not open instead it shows blank page :
I think it is due to match.params.id problem. Can anyone suggest me some solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In **productDetails** component, you can use **useParams**

instead of using **(match.params.id)** use only **(id)**

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const {id} = useParams();
getProductDetails(id)
```